# Is there a way to specify inside visual studio 2008 that an application requires admin?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, uac, manifest

I see plenty of articles on how to embed a manifest file to require admin, but the problem I find with that is we auto-increment the version number number, so a static manifest file doesn't seem like it'd work because we'd have to update the version number each time.

Is there any way to get VS to generate the manifest and embed it automatically and have it updated with the info from the AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Answer (score 1):

We use M4 as part of our build process to update version numbers in our Manifest.

Check it out: http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the application, and select "Add new item". Then select "Application Manifest File".

The app.manifest will allow tell windows what permission level the app needs.

Its extremly easy.

[EDIT]: I'm not sure what you would need to update from the assemblyInfo.cs file.